# Making a blinking div with different colours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div which blinks a certain colour at a time interval , which has a border that blinks at a different time interval.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var promo = document.getElementById('blink');
  var extraBlink = document.getElementById('extraBlink');
  setInterval(function() {
    promo.style.display = (promo.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
  }, 1000);
  setInterval(function() {
    extraBlink.style.display = (extraBlink.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
  }, 500);


});
```

```css
#border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(61, 243, 61);
  border-width: 10px;
}

#promotion {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgb(170, 7, 7);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blink">
  <div id="extraBlink">
    <div id="border">
      <footer id="promotion"> Half Price Today! </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can only manage to make it blink one colour instead of blinking two colours at the same time.

Comment: You dont change the color?

Comment: Please clarify what you want. There are two colors.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I want a box which blinks a colour at a time interval , which has a border that blinks a different colour at a different time interval

Comment: Your current code creates two separate sections. Do you want this or just want the footer to have a background and a border?

Comment: God, this is a throwback to the days of Geocities!

Comment: And, the `<blink>` tag!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using JQuery, you should use it to get references to the elements in question as well as for toggling the styles (instead of setting the styles inline, set up classes that can simply be toggled).

Also, if I understand you correctly, you don't need all that HTML. You really just need the footer and a container element.

Lastly, your CSS needs to be more disbursed between the elements to create the right effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Your already using JQuery so also use it to get the DOM references
  var $promo = $('#promotion');    
  var $border = $('#border');
  
  setInterval(function() {
    $promo.toggleClass("hidden");  // Toggles the show/hide aspect every 1.5 seconds
  }, 1000); 
  
  setInterval(function() {
    $border.toggleClass("border");  // Toggles the border every .5 seconds  
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
/* The container gets positioned and the child content will go for the ride. */
body {
 margin:0;
}
#border {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px; 
  text-align:center;
}

#promotion {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:rgb(170, 7, 7);
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  height:60px;
  margin:10px;
}

.border {
  border:10px solid rgb(61, 243, 61);
}

.hidden { visibility:hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="border">
  <footer id="promotion"> Half Price Today! </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that once you hide the child the parent has no content and thus loses its background and when you hide the parent the child disappears too. You might be able to achieve this with visibility but when you hide the parent it will still hide the child but at least the reserved space when rendering does not disappear thus not jerking all around the surrounding text/html

I modified your code to use plain javascript as an alternative to jQuery class swapping highlighted by Scott Marcus.

```js
self.onload = function(){
    var promo = document.getElementById('blink');
    var extraBlink = document.getElementById('extraBlink');
    setInterval(function() {
        promo.style.backgroundColor  = promo.style.backgroundColor=="yellow"?"magenta":"yellow";
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function() {
     extraBlink.style.backgroundColor = extraBlink.style.backgroundColor=="red"?"blue":"red";
    }, 500);

};
```

```css
#blink{
  border-style: solid;
  padding:10px;
}
#extraBlink{
  border-style: solid;
  padding:10px;
}
.promotion {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="blink">
  <div id="extraBlink">
    <div id="border">
     <footer class="promotion"> Half Price Today! </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```